# Voltage shift from 3.3V to 12V

Tags: raspberry-pi, level-shifting, logic-level

I'd like to use [MX-FS-03V](http://forum.hobbycomponents.com/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1324) 433MHz transmitter together with a Raspberry Pi (RPi).
The Raspberry Pi's outputs have 3.3V, but the MX-FS-03V operates on 3.5-12V (the higher the voltage the higher the transmission distance).

In my understanding, when connecting the MX-FS-03V's VCC to 12V, the DATA input pin must use the same voltage. Is this correct?

The RPi provides 3.3V and 5V, but no 12V. What would be the most simple way to let the MX-FS-03V operate on 12V?

Comment: Use a BJT common emitter amplifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this circuit diagram for the transmitter is correct, you don't need to level-shift your output:

[image]

The TXD pin is the input to the base of an NPN transistor, so all that's necessary is enough voltage to turn on the transistor. Your 3.3v output from the RPi should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! What would be the best way to get 12V from the RPi?

Comment: @squarebracket You might want to have a look at boost convertors or charge pumps.

Comment: @squarebracket The best way would be to use 12V as your main supply and regulate it down to power the RPi.

Comment: Would be a RNM-0512S sufficient (5V to 12V, max. 83 mA)?

Comment: @squarebracket To answer that you need to know how much power the transmitter will draw, and I don't see that specified anywhere.

Comment: @NickJohnson According to http://bit.ly/1BeuG2V the max. current is 28mA and according to http://bit.ly/1DZPITP the max. current is 40mA at 12V.

Comment: @squarebracket Then that boost regulator should be up to it if your 5v power source can supply enough current (eg, not the RPi's USB plug!). Converting down for the RPi is still probably a better idea.